# What happened to Bruce Wayne/Batman's knee?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight-rises

Early in The Dark Knight Rises, Bruce is seen limping with a cane. Some characters allude to an injury sustained from a fight, but we never see this in The Dark Knight. At the conclusion of that film, we see Batman surviving his run-in with Harvey Dent and escaping while *running away*.

**What happened to Bruce Wayne/Batman's knee in between The Dark Knight and The Dark Knight Rises?**

Note: we know the injury is real because we see Bruce requiring a knee brace of some kind prior to him suiting up as Batman.

Comment: He's a superhero without superpowers - he was constantly getting into fights for over seven years, that's gotta do some serious damage...

Comment: @dean He was retired for the 8 years between TDK and TDKR.  This injury isn't mentioned (in TDK) as having occurred during the crime-fighting between BB and TDK.

Comment: Okay the problem is, he's not wearing the knee brace in the pit. How is he able to walk without a limp after losing that brace?

Comment: @chanderson Because he's The Goddamn Batman.

Comment: No idea, but I've seen the movie twice and been bothered by this the whole time: he was limping on his right side for half an hour, and then he fixes this with a brace (lets forget about what kind of injury he had, because I guess they don't care about reality) on his left leg.

Comment: the pit prison is lazarus pit capable of healing and extending life and it heals all batmans injuries :D I dunno

Comment: @amme Probably not what they were going for but I like that idea!

Comment: Maybe he took an arrow to the knee

Answer (score 30, accepted):

During the hospital check up scene, the doctor reveals via x-ray that Bruce Wayne has absolutely no cartilage left in his knee. I'm no doctor, but I think that would make anyone walk with a limp. Thankfully they fix it with that leg gizmo so he doesn't limp for the rest of the movie ;)

Comment: I concur, this is the reason

Comment: But *why* was his cartilage gone?

Comment: @SystemDown down highlights the only thing preventing me from giving you the check: *why* was his cartilage gone?

Comment: Here's a variety of reasons: http://www.regenexx.com/2011/03/the-top-10-causes-of-cartilage-loss/ - but I imagine the most logical ones would be 'Trauma' and 'Repeated Trauma'.

Comment: The cartilage was worn away by constant extreme stress (lots of jumping, running, kicking) with no recovery in between.

Answer (score 10):

It's from the Dark Knight and his fall. At the end of that movie he's also limping after he took down Harvey Dent from a few stories up.

Comment: [I can't see him limping here, just running away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oL7PSlUuWPs)

Comment: @oers: Maybe its adrenaline

Comment: @oers I seem to remember him limping in the end of the movie too.  I think it was before the scene you linked, when he got up.

Comment: The problem with the answer "It's from the fall at the end of The Dark Knight" is that in the scene in The Dark Knight Rises where he has his knee x-rayed and the doctor explains that he has destroyed all the cartilage in his knee is that a single fall would not damage cartilage like that. The way the doctor described it as scar tissue build up would indicate that it was from long term abuse of his leg, not a single injury. While the fall from the scaffolding may have exaserbated the issue, chances are due to the rigorous training and constant stress he had been placing on his body there was a

Comment: Clearly one fall wouldn't cause cartilage injury like that.

Answer (score 8):

According to [about.com](http://osteoarthritis.about.com/od/osteoarthritis101/a/cartilage.htm) cartilage can be worn away for different reasons:

> If a joint is burdened by improper alignment, excessive weight, excessive activity, overuse, or injury, articular cartilage wears away.

**Excessive activity** and **overuse** certainly apply in the case of Bruce Wayne.

I don't think there was one particular incident that caused the cartilage to be worn away but it was just the repeated strain on the body associated with being Batman.

Comment: This is my feeling. He's been furiously Batman-ing for years, he's getting old(er), he's just wearing out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you think that he got injured in the Dark Knight when he tackled Harvey and fell off a (i think 2-3) storey building before he told Gordon to frame him? Because that was a really nasty fall.